# JavaScript - reactivity

Tags: javascript

I have this code. It does that always when there is function, that is interested on some key in Session, it will be called whenever the key changed its value.
The problem is that to track what keys the function is interested, i need to run that function once and it can have some sideffects (if that function will manipulate DOM for instance). How can i run that function without affecting the current environment, if it is possible....?

```
var checkRunning = false;
var keys = [];
var checks = {};

var Session = {
  get: function (key) {
    if (checkRunning) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  },
  set: function (key, value) {
    if (checks[key]) {
      var l = checks[key].lenght;
      for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        checks[key][i]();
      }
    }
  }
};

function check(f) {
  checkRunning = true;
  f();
  checkRunning = false;
  var l = keys.lenght;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (checks[keys[i]]) {
      checks[keys[i]].push(f);      
    }
    else {
      checks[keys[i]] = [f];
    }
  }
  keys = [];
}

//how to use

var a = "something";

check(function () {
  // this function should be run always when Session key "a_dep" will change
  a = Session.get("a_dep");
});

Session.set("a_dep", 10); 
Session.set("a_dep", 20);
```

Comment: If I were you, I would deal with Object.watch. Take a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak: implemented only in Gecko ....

Comment: you can find object watch shim here: https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583

Answer (score 0):

So I refactored your code to achieve what I understood you wanted.

I first redefined `Session` and its getter/setter. I store the values in a literal object with the key to access it :

```
function Session () {
    this.myDictionnary = {};
    this.myCallbacks = {};
}
Session.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
    this.myDictionnary[key] = value;
}
Session.prototype.get = function (key) {
    return this.myDictionnary[key];
}
```

Here we have our core code. Now you want to call a function every time you set a value to a key, so we have to

1. Set a function (or function set) - key couple
2. Call this function (or these functions) when a value is set to key

Note the `myCallbacks` literal object which will handle these couples. So first, create the key - function couple :

```
Session.prototype.callbackWhenSet = function (key, callback) {
    if(!this.myCallbacks[key]) {
        this.myCallbacks[key] = [];
    }
    this.myCallbacks[key].push(callback);
}
```

Then call it when set is called (here I rewrite the `set` function )

```
Session.prototype.set = function (key, value) {
    this.myDictionnary[key] = value;
    if(this.myCallbacks[key]) {
        for(var i = 0; i < this.myCallbacks[key].length; i++) {
          this.myCallbacks[key][i]();  
        }
    }
}
```

Finally we can test it !

```
var test = new Session();

test.callbackWhenSet("a_dep", function () {
    alert("a_dep is set to " + test.get("a_dep"));
});

test.set("a_dep", 10);
test.set("something", 250);
test.set("a_dep", 20);
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cf99M/1/), we have an alert showed each time `"a_dep"` is set.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use [ProAct.js](http://proactjs.github.io) and do stuff like this:

```
var obj = ProAct.prob({
  a: 4
});
obj.p('a').on(function () {
  console.log('obj.a has changed!');
});
```